# Error : parse error on input `='

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm reading the Haskell book : http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses

When I enter this line in the interpreter,

```
removeNonUppercase st = [c | c <- st, c `elem` ['A' .. 'Z']]
```

I get this error:

```
parse error on input `='
```

Whats causing this error ?

Comment: It's best to get into the habit of saving your definitions in a file rather than typing them directly into the interpreter; they're considerably easier to change that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When defining variables or functions in the interpreter or in a GHCi script file (i.e. not a Haskell module), you need to use the `let` keyword.

```
> let removeNonUppercase st = [c | c <- st, c `elem` ['A' .. 'Z']]
```

This is because the interpreter essentially acts as if you were in a global `do`-block. Your code would be OK as-is in a Haskell source file.

If you got this error outside the interpreter, you probably either messed up the indentation, or you have some other syntax error in nearby code.